# Vuejs 2 bind image src

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a table with multiple rows and a `<td>` loading a dynamic url image using Vuetify

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items">
  <template slot="items" scope="props">
      <td>
         <img :src="getImgUrl(props.item.styleCode)" />
      </td>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

and then

```
checkImage(imageSrc, good, bad) {
   let img = new Image();
   img.onload = good;
   img.onerror = bad;
   img.src = imageSrc;
},
getImgUrl(styleCode) {
  var image = 'http://192.168.1.19/Images/ClassImages/' + styleCode + '.png';

  this.checkImage(image,
  function () {
     return 'http://192.168.1.19/Images/ClassImages/' + styleCode + '.png';
  }, function () {
     return 'http://192.168.1.19/Images/ClassImages/default.png';
  });
}
```

This return nothing.
What are I doing bad?

Edit: This is to load an external image and if doesn't exist load a default image

Comment: You're not returning anything in either method

Comment: It's a callback that work properly if I write console.log('good') of console.log('bad') in the getImgUrl function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not returning anything in the `getImgUrl` method, meaning you're not binding the `src` attribute to anything.

It'd be much simpler to attempt to set the src and then use an `@error` listener directly on the `img` element to handler the event of a failed load:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    getImgUrl(i) {
      if (i === 4) {
       return 'http://thisonewontwork';
      }
      return 'http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image' + i;
    },
    onError(e) {
      let defaultURL = 'http://placehold.it/120x120&text=default';
      if (e.target.src !== defaultURL) {
        e.target.src = defaultURL;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template v-for="i in 4">
    <img :src="getImgUrl(i)" @error="onError">  
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: I was using this <img :src="getImgUrl(props.item.styleCode)" onerror="this.onerror = null; this.src = 'http://192.168.1.19/Images/ClassImages/no_image_mdpi.png';"/> but I think your solution is cleaner. Thanks

Comment: I was trying avoid the 404 not found in the console with my approach...