# Vue/Vuefire: Ok, I can open a modal, save a image file to firebase, but can't get it to view without a refresh

Tags: javascript, image, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2

Lots of pieces, got them all working except one!

I can open a modal window, do a firebase image upload (with the correct call back to make sure the upload worked), save the image to firebase storage (using vuefire). And close the modal.

The image DOES NOT show up until I do a manual refresh, then displays fine. Also if the image has been cached, it works OK. Just can't figure out why I can't view the new image without that manual refresh.

CODE

HTML to Display image: edit.vue

```
<div>
    <img :src="showPhoto()" id="showPhoto" name="showPhoto" />
</div>
```

VUE code to populate html and open modal

```
    showModal: function() {
        this.$modal.show('save')
      },
      showPhoto: function () {

        const photoName = this.residentObj['photo']

        console.log('photoName', photoName)

        if (photoName) {

          const gsReference = storage.refFromURL('gs://connect-the-dots-ef09c.appspot.com/images/' + this.$route.params.id + 
          '/' + photoName).getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {

            var img = document.getElementById('showPhoto')
            img.src = url
          })
        }
      }
```

Save uploaded image close modal, go back the parent page. I can push a new route, but that has no effect even though the image has changed.

save.vue

```
 methods: {
    onFileChange(e) {
      const file = e.target.files[0];

      const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('images/' + this.$route.params.id + '/' + file.name);

   residentsRef.child(this.$route.params.id).update({photo:file.name});

    storageRef.put(file).then(function(result) {

    alert("OK, file uploaded!")

// this has no effect, and probably dont want to refresh the entire page this the "img src"
 // this.$router.push({name: 'edit', params: { id: this.$route.params.id }});

    }});

    this.closeModal ()

    });
```

Summary: I can save an image to firebase using vue/vuefire, but can't view the new image unless I do a manual refresh. A cached image works fine.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: You're setting `src` equal to the result of `showPhoto` and that function doesn't return a value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vuejs 2 bind image src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945091/vuejs-2-bind-image-src)

Comment: If run the router.push again, still does not display the image.  Refreshing manually, the image pops right in.  This does not work when coming from the modal, yet it should:  // this.$router.push({name: 'edit', params: { id: this.$route.params.id }});

Comment: This code does return a value:  var img = document.getElementById('showPhoto')
            img.src = url   and the image updates. It's just when coming from the modal, nothing updates.